# this.props.location is undefined when passing props with Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

React beginner here, stuck again. I get a this.props.location undefined error when passing props through multiple components. I add props to Link component, then pass them to Route component and pass them again to Link output component.

List / Link component

```
import React from "react";
import "./ProductList.css";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

class ProductList extends React.Component {
    render() { 
        const products = this.props.products;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Product List</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>EAN Code</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Weight</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>Active</th>
                    </tr>
                    {products.map((product, index) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                <td>{product.name}</td>
                                <td>{product.ean}</td>
                                <td>{product.type}</td>
                                <td>{product.weight}</td>
                                <td>{product.color}</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" checked={product.active} onChange={(e) => this.props.setProductActive(product, e.target.checked)} /></td>
                                <td><Link to={{ pathname: "/view", prodIndex: {index}}} ><button>View</button></Link></td>
                                <td><button>Edit</button></td>
                                <td><button onClick={() => this.props.deleteProduct(index)}>Delete</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ProductList;
```

The App / Route component

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ProductList from "../ProductList/ProductList";
import NewProd from "../NewProd/NewProd";
import ViewProd from "../ViewProd/ViewProd";
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            name: "", 
            ean: "", 
            type: "", 
            weight: "", 
            color: "", 
            active: false,
            products: [{name: "Cabbage", ean: "00000000", type: "Vegetable", weight: "2kg", color: "Green", active: false}, 
            {name: "Banana", ean: "111111111", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.3kg", color: "Yellow", active: false}, 
            {name: "Chocolate", ean: "22222222222", type: "Candy", weight: "0.2kg", color: "Brown", active: false}, 
            {name: "Orange", ean: "3333333333", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.5kg", color: "Orange", active: false}, 
            {name: "Cucumber", ean: "4444444444", type: "Vegetable", weight: "1kg", color: "Green", active: false}, ]
    };
};

handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let products = [...this.state.products];

  products.push({
      name: this.state.name,
      ean: this.state.ean,
      type: this.state.type,
      weight: this.state.weight,
      color: this.state.color,
      active: false,
  });
  this.setState({ products, name: "", ean: "", type: "", weight: "", color: "", active: false}
  );
}
handleInputChange = (e) => {
  let input = e.target;
  let name = e.target.name;
  let value = input.value;
  this.setState({[name]: value})
  };

deleteProduct = (delIndex) => {
  let products = [...this.state.products].filter((product, index) => index !== delIndex);
  this.setState({ products });
};
isActive = () => {
  this.setState({active: !this.state.active})
}
setProductActive = (product, active) => {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    products: state.products.map(p => p.name === product.name ? { ...p, active } : p)
  }))
}
render() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <ProductList products={this.state.products} 
      deleteProduct={this.deleteProduct}
      setProductActive={this.setProductActive} />
      <NewProd handleFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
      handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
      newName={this.state.name}
      newEan={this.state.ean}
      newType={this.state.type}
      newWeight={this.state.weight}
      newColor={this.state.color} />
      <Route path="/view" render={(props) => <ViewProd {...props} products={this.state.products} 
      prodIndex={this.props.location.prodIndex} />} />
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The Output component

```
import React from "react";
import "./ViewProd.css";

class ViewProd extends React.Component {
    render() { 
        const products = this.props.products;
        const index = this.props.prodIndex;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>View Product</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>{`Name: ${products[{index}].name}`}</li>
                    <li>{`EAN Code: ${products[{index}].ean}`}</li>
                    <li>{`Type: ${products[{index}].type}`}</li>
                    <li>{`Weight: ${products[{index}].weight}`}</li>
                    <li>{`Color: ${products[{index}].color}`}</li>
                    <li>{`Active: ${products[{index}].active}`}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ViewProd;
```

The goal is, when you press the view button, it opens the viewProduct component with the information list. I'm struggling with displaying the information of a product with specific index. I want to pass the index from ProductList component to ViewProd component and it needs to go through Link and React components as far as I'm aware. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object) best way is to do it like this.

```
<td><Link to={{ pathname: "/view", state: { prodIndex: {index} }}} ><button>View</button></Link></td>
```

And then you do not need to pass it through the route/app component. It will be automatically available in the props of component rendered using the render function of `<Route>`.

In `ViewProd.js`

```
const index = this.props.location.state.prodIndex;
```

Remove this from your App/Route component

```
prodIndex={this.props.location.prodIndex}
```

location is not available here and it will give you an error because you are trying to access a key in `undefined`.